# Using the last line of an inline element as the width for :after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, width, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm facing an issue that I'm struggling to overcome.

This is best demonstrated with an example I guess:

**As a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wchv2hmn/3/

**In the browser:**

```css
div {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    
}
span:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>
        htejuteujetjtjehrehreheherhrehrehre sghosgjosjoskoskfosjofshohofshofusofhrehrhrehehhrehrherheheuorfos
    </span>
</div>
```

I need the `:after` pseudo element to take on the width of the last line of text within the `<span>`, not the first.

Adding inline-block to the span, results in the text just being displayed as a block level element, as seen here in chrome and Firefox 39:

```css
div {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    display:inline-block;
    
}
span:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>
        htejuteujetjthehtehtehethetje sghosgjosjoskoskfosjofshohofshofusethehetthehehterfos
    </span>
</div>
```

It's as if the `<span>`s `min-width` is set to the length the `<span>` will occupy when all the text fits on one line. So when the window shrinks, and the text splits to occupy two or more lines, the width can't shrink any smaller than it's *assumed* `min-width`...

Does anyone have any ideas? Preferably without having to alter the DOM, although it can be done if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the span as block element.
Html

```
<div>
<span>
    htejuteujetjtje  sghosgjosjoskoskfosjofshohofshofusofuorfos
</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
background-color: blue; 
}
span {
position: relative;
background-color: green;
}

span{display:block;}

span:after {
content: '';
display: block;
height: 10px;
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Display block will make the span a 100% width of the parent. This is not what I want. The element has to be inline, but use the last line as it's relative position width... I've updated my question to better represent the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block` to span style

```
 span {
     position: relative;
     background-color: green;
     display:inline-block;
 }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works with the '<br/>', but if it's removed (as it is in the real world scenario), then the '<span>' again becomes 100% of the width of the parent.

Comment: Well, it works for me even without `<br/>`. Maybe it depends on browser? I checked it in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Xw31q91.png -- Is what I get in Firefox 39... As you can see, the blue is gone, and the green has completely taken over.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m03z5bmf/ Firefox 40.0.3, red line is only under text (also with `<br/>`)

Comment: You're missing my point. The blue is no longer visible as it has a 100% width, block level element inside of it. The span needs to be inline, not a block element... Can you see **blue** in your fiddle, in your browser?

Comment: I added my fiddle result picture.

Comment: Is that image using the '<br />'? It looks like it is. With the '<br />' it works correctly. Without it, and the screensize being adjusted so that it splits to two lines, it does not... If it's just from your fiddle, then I'm confused. Neither chrome, nor Firefox 39 are displaying it the way your image suggests.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem with resizing now.

Comment: Playing with the fiddles, it shows some unusual behavior. When the window is stretch so that the span text can be shown on a single line, it acts as an inline element. Once the window is decreased in size however, and the text splits to occupy two lines, the width of the span doesn't shrink down. It's as if it's min-width is set to it's largest possible size, regardless of the number of lines the text occupies.